# Best way to create a deep cloned object literal from an object with accessors?

Tags: javascript, getter

I have an object that is a combination of literals and accessors:

```
const obj = {
   stuff: [],
   get processedStuff() { return this.stuff.map(el => `${el}!`) }
}

obj.stuff = ['woot']
console.log(obj.processedStuff) // ['woot!']
```

I want to create a deepClone of obj so that the clone behaves entirely like a literal.  So in the clone, changes to stuff will no longer result in changes to processedStuff:

```
const obj2 = cl0n3Me(obj)
obj2.stuff = ['nope']
console.log(obj.processedStuff) // ['woot!']
```

Using a library function like cloneDeep in lodash doesn't do this -- the accessors come along for the ride and are a part of the new obj.

I can do this with the following...

```
const obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

...however I am not sure if that is this the most efficient way / recommended way to do this.

What say ye javascript masters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a deep clone with using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). afaik, there are no downsides but could be wrong. in my testing it works for your example. it should be noted that this is not a complete deep cloning solution, as it won't handle `Date` or `Map` cloning without additional code to handle those types.

```
function clone( o ) {
    if(Array.isArray(o)){
        const o2 = [...o];
        for(let i=0;i<o2.length;i++){
            if(typeof o2[i]==='object'&&o2[i]!==null){
                o2[i]=clone(o2[i]);
            }
        }
        return o2;
    }else{
        const o2 = {...o};
        for(let k in o2){
            if(typeof o2[k]==='object'&&o2[k]!==null){
                o2[k]=clone(o2[k]);
            }
        }
        return o2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, appreciate it!  Any thoughts as to whether or not doing it that way is more/less efficient that just JSON.stringify and then JSON.parse?

Comment: well obviously its more efficient to do it the way i illustrate above. wherein so much as both methods will create the same number of new object/array etc refs in the resulting clone, the json method also will introduce the overhead of serializing/deserializing. it  also wouldn't work with `Map` or `Date` since those aren't serializable, however my example wouldn't work either without more work to handle those types as they wouldn't be cloned(each obj would still have boxed pointers to same objects in memory).